# FindOne in mongoose returns undefined

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

When im consoling all the data int he database using Find method, an object with Title:'day1' is present in it but when I perform findOne operation I get undefined as output.
Please help me.

```
 Post.findOne({ Title: 'day1'}).then(function(err, result){console.log(result)});
```

Comment: when using Promise, the first argument is your payload (err is result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the following query instead**

```
Post.findOne({ Title: 'day1'},function(err,data)
{
  if(err)
    { res.send(err)}
  else if(data)
    {res.send(data)}
})
```

Comment: You are simply using a callback instead of Promise mode. What will this change?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you mixed up callback with Promise..

If you will use Callback method you can use the following code:

```
Post.findOne({Title: 'day1'}, (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).send(err); // If there is an error stop the function and throw an error
    }
    res.status(200).send(data) // If there is no error send the data
})
```

If you are going to use the promise method:

```
Post.findOne({Title: 'day1'})
.then(data => res.status(200).send(data)) // Send data if no errors
.catch(err => res.status(404).send(err)) // Throw an error if something happens
```